# How To Watch Webview Actions

Tags: android, webview

I have a payment url, which is called in webview and I need to know whats happening.

Can we watch whats happening in web view, since I am calling a payment url, I need to track for its failure or success.

Can we achieve it? How?

Comment: Please, you need to provide some code, otherwise this question shuold be flagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this way to track your payment is success or failed

```
paymentWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains(Your Predefine sucess URL)) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("result", "sucess");
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
                return true;
            } else if (url.contains(Your Predefine faild URL)) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("result", "faild");
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (pbWebLoader != null) {
                pbWebLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```